# Setting date value in a database field when input in Null

Tags: c#, database, datetime

I am trying to set an condition when setting up parameter for a database field so that if the receiving value is null then it should set it to current date

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePlannedEnd", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pm.DatePlannedEnd != null ? pm.DatePlannedEnd : DateTime.Now.Date;
```

I get error:

> Type of conditional expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion between string and System.Date.Time

`DatePlannedEnd` is a Date field in the database. Any idea what will be the right way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: what is the type of `pm.DatePlannedEnd `? is it `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up Add and AddWithValue.  The whole point of AddWithValue is that you provide the value, not the type, of the parameter.  The type is inferred from the value.  If you're going to set the Value property explicitly then call Add, not AddWithValue.

Apart from that, why are you specifying the type as NVarChar and then assigning a DateTime as the value?  If the data type in the database is date then the SqlDbType should be Date, not NVarChar.  If you use AddWithValue though, that will be inferred.

Comment: The database field is date. Even when I change it to Date, I get the same error: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePlannedEnd", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = pm.DatePlannedEnd != null ? pm.DatePlannedEnd : DateTime.Now.Date;

Comment: Perhaps follow the instructions I provided then.  I said either call Add and set the Value property or just call AddWithValue.  You're still calling AddWithValue, specifying the type instead of the value and then setting the Value property.  One or the other.  At the moment, that code is trying to set SqlDbType.DateTime as the value of the parameter, which is obviously not what you want and is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two different types from a ternary expression.

You're adding `DateTime.Now` as a date, but your parameter type is a string. Convert it to a string first.

Also, use one method or the other of adding parameters, not a combination of both.

```
var datePlannedEnd = pm.DatePlannedEnd ?? DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DatePlannedEnd", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@DatePlannedEnd"].Value = datePlannedEnd;
```

Or:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePlannedEnd", datePlannedEnd);
```

And if you have any control over the database, think about altering that column type to be a date instead of a string. That way, you won't have to parse a string back into a valid DateTime whenever you get the value back out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the value first before submitting against the database :)

```
if (pm.DatePlannedEnd == null) {
pm.DatePlannedEnd = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
}
```